# How to check textarea for invalid characters

Tags: javascript, regex

The table below is part of the contact form. Validation of all other input fields works fine except the textarea which is for client message. The script is expected to search for invalid xters. If found, an alarm message is turned on.
The text area can contain more than one line.
SO far, if any invalid xter is at the beginning in the textarea, an alarm message is turend on.
However if the invalid xter is not at the beginning of the input, the script does not detect it. 
i have tried some solutions I came across but none is working. The best I have so far is this.
Please what is wrong with my script?
Also I want to allow these xters  , . ( ), - How can include it in my regex if possible?

```
<table id="contactustbl">
<tr>
<th class='nobrd'>Your message*</th>
<td>
<textarea style='width:250px;height:150px' class='contactusinput'  
id='mymessage' name='mymessage' type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9,._- ]"  
maxlength='2000'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class='alarm' id='mymessagealarm'><i></i></p>
```

The script:

```
<script>
function validatemessage() {
    var message_regex = /^[\d\w\s]/m;
    var val = $("#mymessage").val();    
    //check if textarea is empty
    if (val == "") {
    $("#mymessagealarm").text('You must fill this field');      
    }
    //Check for invalid xters in textarea
    if (!message_regex.test(val)) {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('Incorrect pattern Use only A-Z a-z 0-9  
        ,._- and space');               
    } else {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('');
        $("#mymessageerr").text(0); 
    }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML remains same. Th script (thanks to Johan Karlsson) is as follows:

```
<script>
$('#mymessage').keyup(validatemessage);
function validatemessage() {
    var message_regex = /[^\d\w\s,.;()- _ ]/m;
    var val = $("#mymessage").val();
    //var each = val.split(" ");
    //check if textarea is empty
    if (val == "") {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('You must fill this field');          
    }
    //Check for invalid xters
    if (message_regex.test(val)) {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('Incorrect pattern Use only A-Z a-z 0-9  
        ,._- and space');                       
    } else {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('');              
    }   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanking on SO can be expressed with upvotes (you have that privilege BTW). Also, if some of the answers here helped you with the solution, you can mark them as accepted and publish your working code in the question - no need to post a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\d\w\s]/m
```

`^` here means start of a line. I think what you are looking for are:

```
/[^\d\w\s]/m
```

and to add `, . ( )` :

```
/[^\d\w\s,.()]/m
```

and then you need to remove `!` from your `if`:

```
if (message_regex.test(val)) {
```

Comment: `\w` encapsulates `\d`, so that can be removed from the regex.

Comment: This works fine. See the solution below. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to note:

- `pattern` attribute is not working for textarea, so you need to implement your own function
- the regex you have contains an issue: the `_-`  creates a range from `_` till a space (it should cause an "invalid range" error, but I guess the first issue prevents you from getting that far)
- To check multiline input, you need to actually split the text into separate lines and check each of them otherwise, a single correct line will make the whole text pass.

Here is my suggested code fix:

```js
$('#mymessage').keyup(validatemessage);

function validatemessage() {
  var textarea = this;
  var message_regex = new RegExp('^' + $(textarea).attr('pattern') + '$');
  var val = $("#mymessage").val();
  //check if textarea is empty
  if (val === "") {
    $("#mymessagealarm").text('You must fill this field');
  } else {
    //Check for invalid xters in textarea
    var lines = val.split(/[\r\n]+/);
    $.each(lines, function(index, line) {
      if (!message_regex.test(line)) {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('Incorrect pattern Use only A-Z a-z 0-9  , ._ - and space ');
      } else {
        $("#mymessagealarm").text('');
        $("#mymessageerr").text(0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="contactustbl">
  <tr>
    <th class='nobrd'>Your message*</th>
    <td>
      <textarea style='width:250px;height:150px' class='contactusinput' id='mymessage' name='mymessage' type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9,._ -]*" maxlength='2000'></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p class='alarm' id='mymessagealarm'><i></i></p>
```

Comment: This isn't working as well. Whatever the textarea input, I get same message 'Incorrect pattern...' I suspect the error may be either the line var lines = val.split(/[\r\n]+/) or message_regex.test(line). Question where does the variable line come in? Only lines was defined as variable not line. However I solved the problem, see below

Comment: My code does not show any error when you input letters, numbers, spaces, `,`, `.`, `_` and `-`. `line` is each line in your textarea (see `function(index, line)`). By splitting with `/[\r\n]+/` the input is split into lines. There is no error - just check the console log.

Comment: Thanks. I have probed this. The console log is clear. Error is from another script associated with yours. thanks